# Rest Assured Bearer authentication

Tags: java, api, authentication, rest-assured, bearer-token

I am new to using Rest Assured,Java and Api testing so please be gentle with me. When I use rest assured to test an api that uses Bearer authentication the tests fail resulting in:-
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

I know the issue is likely to do with the authentication but am unsure on how to use "Bearer". I searched around and believe that somehow I need to make an initial request using my username and password. Then get a token back to be used  for bearer authentication. 
Please can someone help me to do this with a very simple example?

My code is

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;

@BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        RestAssured.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails();
        RestAssured.authentication =   preemptive().basic("username","password");

}

@Test
public void successfulTest() {
    given()
            .contentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    when().

            get("http://mydomain/testpath/Id=2").
    then().
            statusCode(200);

}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
Response response =
      given()
          .headers(
              "Authorization",
              "Bearer " + bearerToken,
              "Content-Type",
              ContentType.JSON,
              "Accept",
              ContentType.JSON)
          .when()
          .get(url)
          .then()
          .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
          .extract()
          .response();
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to get the bearer token you can use this code to authorize your request:

```
PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme authScheme = new PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme();
authScheme.setUserName("login");
authScheme.setPassword("password");
RestAssured.authentication = authScheme;
```

After you get the token, send it in your request this way:

```
response = given().auth().oauth2(token).get("http://mydomain/testpath/Id=2");
```

Answer (score 0):

My Cucumber step definition looks like this:

```
    // Class variables
    private String token_resource = "/yourApp/oauth/token?username=";
    private String endpoint_rest="https://your.app.domain.com/";
    private String acessToken;

    @When("^user gets access token using userId \"(.+)\" and password \"(.+)\"$")
public void getAccessToken(String userName, String password){
    RequestSpecification requestSpec = RestAssured.with();
    requestSpec.given().contentType("application/json");
    requestSpec.headers("Authorization", "Basic  your-string-here");
    Response response = requestSpec.post(endpoint_rest + token_resource + userName + "&password=" + password + "&client_id=yourApp&grant_type=password");
    String responseMsg = response.asString();
    System.out.println(">> responseMsg=" + responseMsg);
    assertTrue("Missing access token",responseMsg.contains("access_token"));
    System.out.println(">> Get Access token RESPONSE: " + responseMsg);

    DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(responseMsg);
    acessToken= doc.read("access_token");

    System.out.println(" >> doc.read access_token= " + acessToken);  
}
```

Much depends on how your endpoint was coded.

When I want to learn this kind of thing I go to the Rest-assured [examples](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/tree/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/resources) and search.

[Here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/7cc7503b66d17fffa7d6f8442e3838a9b0d5f7b8/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/io/restassured/itest/java/OAuthITest.java) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If the error was "Connection refused", it sounds more like a network issue instead of authentication. Basically you haven't reached the point to authenticate your client with the service.
You can check to see if your service is running on a different port other than 80. If that's the case, just provide the port before sending out the request:

```
given().port(your_port_number)
```

You can use a more visualized rest client app to try your request to make sure it actually works before putting it into your code. "Postman" could be a good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response postResponse = given().headers(cookieName, "Bearer " + cookieValue, "Content-Type",
                ContentType.JSON, "Accept", ContentType.JSON)
    .when().get(url).then().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .extract().response();
```