# How to send bearer token authorization in rest assured for api testing

Tags: api, automation, rest-assured, bearer-token

in my application, I need to send the bearer token as `authorization` before getting call

I tried this

```
RestAssured.given().auth().oauth2(token).when().get("/search").then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
```

Comment: Have you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790021/rest-assured-bearer-authentication

Comment: What is the error you are getting after using above code?

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

```
RestAssured.given().header("Authorization", "bearer " + token).when().get("/search").then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
```